# Batch file to unzip then rename its jpgs sequentially

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have this structure:

```
Biographies <base folder>
----Elon Musk <person #1 folder>
----|---Modern-Day Genius <chapter name folder>
----|-------Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius.txt <person #1's biography>
----|-------Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius.zip <50-100 photos of person #1>
----|-----------Driving a Tesla.jpg <photo 1>
----|-----------Elon Musk on the train.jpg <photo 2>
----|-----------SpaceX factory.jpg <photo ...>
----Steve Jobs <person #2 folder>
----|---Visionary <chapter name folder>
----|-------Steve Jobs - Visionary.txt <bio>
----|-------Steve Jobs - Visionary.zip <zip of photos>
----|-----------At his home in California.jpg <photo 1>
----|-----------At work on the first iPhone.jpg <photo 2>
----|-----------Steve Jobs yelling at people.jpg <photo ...>
```

I'm looking to 1) unzip the .zip file (using 7zip)
               2) rename the extracted .jpgs using A) the text file name + B) an incremented number.

```
So, you'd end up with:

Under the "Modern-Day Genius" folder, you'd have:
Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 001.jpg
Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 002.jpg
Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 003.jpg
```

because "Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius" was the root filename of the txt file and 001-00n because of some counter.

```
and under the "Visionary" folder, you'd have:
Steve Jobs - Visionary 001.jpg
Steve Jobs - Visionary 002.jpg
Steve Jobs - Visionary 003.jpg

etc.
```

Pieces of this process sound easy enough but I have literally spent 20 hours trying to figure this out over the last week. I'm not brand new to Windows batch files, but I'm not very good at it. Obviously. ;-) I've read a hundred or so posts, examples, 'tutorials', etc. and I'm not finding pieces of solutions anywhere online. I've tried so many variants and have a dozen batch files that sort of do, but don't really work.

I think figuring this out would be of benefit not only to me but to a bunch of other people trying to unzip a file, the rename its contents based on some external parameter. Seems pretty universally useful.

Here's one example but not one w/ renumbering. I have 'working' renumbering batch files, but they don't really work (they rename the first file only, etc.) it's a mess. I'm hoping someone much smarter than me at this stuff can help figure something out.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\

for %%t in ('dir /b *.txt) do (
set textfilename=%%t)

7z e *.zip

for /f %%a in ('dir/b *.jpg) do (
rename "*.jpg" "!textfilename! - *.jpg"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you start in Biographies and recursively search zips,
unzip jpg's from them into the same folder and
rename these with the name of the zip file and an incremented number. 
Using a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and afterwards [for var modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) `~` this isn't to hard.

This batch:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:: CD /D "X:\Biographies"
For /f "delims=" %%Z in ('Dir /B/S *.zip') Do (
  Pushd "%%~dpZ"
  7z.exe e "%%~Z" *.jpg >Nul 2>&1
  Set Cnt=1000
  For %%J in (*.jpg) Do (
    Set /A Cnt+=1
    Ren "%%J" "%%~nZ !Cnt:~-3!%%~xJ"&&Echo Renamed  "%%J" to "%%~nZ !Cnt:~-3!%%~xJ"
  )
  PopD
)
```

Has this sample output.

```
Renamed  "Elon Musk on the train.jpg" to "Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 001.jpg"
Renamed  "Driving a Tesla.jpg" to "Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 002.jpg"
Renamed  "SpaceX factory.jpg" to "Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 003.jpg"

Renamed  "Steve Jobs yelling at people.jpg" to "Steve Jobs - Visionary 001.jpg"
Renamed  "At his home in California.jpg" to "Steve Jobs - Visionary 002.jpg"
Renamed  "At work on the first iPhone.jpg" to "Steve Jobs - Visionary 003.jpg"
```

This is a tree output of the resulting structure.

```
 > tree /F Biographies
X:\BIOGRAPHIES
 ├───Elon Musk
 │   └───Modern-Day Genius
 │           Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 001.jpg
 │           Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 002.jpg
 │           Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius 003.jpg
 │           Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius.txt
 │           Elon Musk - Modern-Day Genius.zip
 │
 └───Steve Jobs
     └───Visionary
             Steve Jobs - Visionary 001.jpg
             Steve Jobs - Visionary 002.jpg
             Steve Jobs - Visionary 003.jpg
             Steve Jobs - Visionary.txt
             Steve Jobs - Visionary.zip
```

Comment: I like your technique of using `Cnt` from `1000`, then only taking the lower 3 digits.   Better than my version!

Comment: @abelenky Thanks. AT:user3450848 The order of my numbering not being alphabetical stems from my test folder drive lying on a FreeNAS Samba server not an NTFS formatted drive where the alpha-sorting is inherent. I could use a second for /f with a dir /B/ON instead.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you for your very quick response and your explanation. I'm going through your file line by line to understand. and looking up every part. I'm confused to what ~xJ means in the REN line. I see you're on a Samba server, so maybe that's why, but in Win7 the .jpg files start their numbering at 002 instead of 001. I'm so grateful for your help in trying to teach this to me and others reading this. My hands were aching from renaming thousands of files manually yesterday. The StackOverflow community is awesome.

Comment: `%%~xJ` simply takes the extension from the currently processed jpg file this part could be replaced by a literal `.jpg` If the counter is initialized with 1000 it should begin with 001 also on ntfs dries, my comment only states that 001 isn't the first alphabetical file on non NTFS drives.

Comment: Inserted some links to ss64.com above.

Comment: @LotPings, BTW I think I understand your logic: from the 'base' biographies folder look recursively for any zip file (Z) and assign the temporary variable Z. Then in the present working dir that holds each zip  extract the zips, and hide any error msgs. Set a 'base' counter, then for any jpg (J) found apply a counter of +1 (which is where the count problem starting w/ 2 is...but I don't know) and rename the jpg from it's original name to: the zip filename (Z) + a space + the rightmost 3 chars of counter (counting leftward) + ~xJ. (not sure what ~xJ is) then echo what you've done and go to PopD

Comment: re: %%~xJ. Oh, I see, okay, cool. I guess we were typing at the same time. Thanks again, very cool.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the `.txt` file:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do ( set Prefix=%%~na)
```

*(example: `%PREFIX%` will be set to `Modern-Day Genius`)*

Putting it together with some pretty straightforward numbering code:

```
@echo off    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do ( set Prefix=%%~na)

set ZEROS=0000000
set COUNTER=1
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    set Value=%ZEROS%%COUNTER%
    set Value=!VALUE:~-3!
    echo rename %%a "%PREFIX% - !VALUE!"
    set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1 )
```

I'm not going to deal with recursing into multiple directories, or dealing with ZIP files.  It looks like you can handle that part.

Comment: Thank you @abelenky for your help! I'm going through your file now line by line like I did w/ LotPings' code.